# How to stop JProgressBar on parent?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jprogressbar

I am working on an application where I am using JprogressBar, When I am doing something then progress bar is running. I also added escape functionality there. when anyone click on Escape button of keyboard then focused Jpanel/Jdialog/JFrame is  dispose.It working fine. My problem is that JprogressBar is not getting stopped. I want to do that if any Jpanel/Jdialog/JFrame is getting closed through escape button then if it's parent have JProgressBar then it should be getting stopped. How can I do this? Parents of all Jpanel/Jdialog/JFrame can be different?

**My Escape Functionality is as above :**

```
public static void setDisposeOnEsc(JComponent c, final Object promptControl) {
        Action escape = new AbstractAction() {

            {
                putValue(NAME, "escape");
            }

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JComponent source = (JComponent) e.getSource();
                    try {
                        Window window = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(source);
                        window.dispose();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                    }
                    try {
                        Dialog dialog = (Dialog) source.getFocusCycleRootAncestor();
                        dialog.dispose();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                    }
                    try {
                        JFrame jFrame = (JFrame) source.getFocusCycleRootAncestor();
                        jFrame.dispose();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                    }   
            }
        };
        Object name = escape.getValue(Action.NAME);
c.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ESCAPE"),name);
        c.getActionMap().put(name, escape);
    }
```

**I want to do that if any Jpanel/Jdialog/JFrame which getting disposed through above method,then if it's parent have JprogressBar and is running then it should be stopped.**

My English is not so good,so please ignore grammar mistakes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for better help sooner edit your question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), that demonstrated your issues with [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) and [JProgressBar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html), because in the code I can't see anyone

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I understand, but you could use something like

```
public static <T extends Component> List<T> findAllChildren(JComponent component, Class<T> clazz) {

    List<T> lstChildren = new ArrayList<T>(5);
    for (Component child : component.getComponents()) {

        if (clazz.isInstance(child)) {

            lstChildren.add((T) child);

        }

        if (child instanceof JComponent) {

            lstChildren.addAll(findAllChildren((JComponent)child, clazz));

        }

    }

    return Collections.unmodifiableList(lstChildren);

}
```

To find all the references to JProgressBar, from there you can do what you want...